# Как создать кортежи файлов в Python из разных папок, но не из своей?

Tags: python, ос, комбинаторика, tuple

Мне необходимо сравнить файлы, причем так, чтобы они лежали в разных папках. Например, есть директории `spk1`, `spk2` и `spk3`, и в каждой - свои 4 файла. Построить кортежи мне надо из каждого файла папки `spk1` с каждым одним файлом `spk2` и с каждым одним файлом `spk3`, но не с каким файлом самой папки `spk1`.
Построить кортеж помогает код:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Voices/'):
    res = list(combinations(files, 2)) # получаем списки кортежей: [(файл 1, файл 2), (файл 1, файл 3)...(файл 3, файл 4)]
```

Однако здесь я получаю пары из файлов одной и той же папки (`spk1`, `spk2` и `spk3`). Мне же требуется обратная ситуация.

Структура папок (стрелками показал, как мне необходимо строить кортежи - и так по всем директориям `spk` и всех их файлам):

[image: Структура папок]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я пока что придумал только такое решение проблемы:

```py
from itertools import product, chain
from os import walk

all_files = dict()
for root, dirs, files in walk("Voices/"):
    all_files[root] = files

for root in all_files.copy():
    files = all_files[root]
    del all_files[root]
    other_files = list(chain(*[all_files[key] for key in all_files]))

    result = list(product(files, other_files))
    print(result)
```

Оно не самое оптимальное по ресурсам, если файлов/папок будет очень много, то его надо будет доработать.

Answer (score 0):

как то не совсем понятно, но возможно речь идет об этом:

```
from os import walk
from itertools import product, chain

top = r'C:\temp\test'  # путь к папкам
_, sampl, *tests = [f for _,_,f in walk(top)]  # первую папку пропускаем (нет файлов), вторая - образцы

res = list(product(sampl, chain(*tests)))  # пары (файл образец + файл из других папок)
```